# Why doesn't this show two overlapping histograms?

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I've essentially got this code that's supposed to display the estimated and theoretical marginals of some change:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

p = 0.22
new_p = 0.24

def draw_hist():
    x = [0, 1]
    theory_y = [new_p, 1 - new_p]
    estimate_y = [p, 1 - p]
    plt.hist(x, estimate_y, alpha=0.5, label='estimated marginal')
    plt.hist(x, theory_y, alpha=0.5, label='theoretical marginal')
    plt.legend(loc='upper right')
    plt.show()

draw_hist()
```

But I get an empty plot as output, is this a wrong use of the histograms or something? The content is not really what is important but more the behaviour of matplotlib.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `plt.bar` -- a barplot -- and not histogram. You just have some x values and corresponding y values. The nature of histogram data is different. See [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/statistics/hist.html) for example. This is a typical confusion between barplots and histogram which I have seen a couple of times on SO.

```
x = np.array([0, 1])
theory_y = [new_p, 1 - new_p]
estimate_y = [p, 1 - p]
plt.bar(x+0.1, estimate_y, alpha=0.5, width=0.2, color='red', label='estimated marginal')
plt.bar(x-0.1, theory_y, alpha=0.5, width=0.2, color='green', label='theoretical marginal')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xticks(x)
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's at least an improvement. Would it be possible to have it a bit differently, where on the x-axis you have 0 and 1. And then above every x value (0 and 1) two bars displaying the estimate_y and theory_y respectively?

Comment: That is already much better, thanks. could the bars for every x_value be separate bars. So you would end up with 4 bars in total? 2 for a value of 0, and 2 for a value of 1.

Comment: There are two bars for 0 and two bars for 1. Look closely. The y values are rather similar that's why you don't see them clearly.

Comment: Oh you're correct, what I meant was. To have them standing next to eachother?

Comment: Ok, check the edit. P.S: I converted x to a numpy array to add and subtract